# collectAsync equivalent in pyspark

Tags: asynchronous, pyspark

I need to schedule some database inserts (influxdb.write_points) in tasks over cluster.
The RDDPipeline.collect returns the deferred tasks.
But it just gets stuck there.

Is there something similar to collectAsync?